# Conditional WHERE clause in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below is a simplified example of a stored procedure I've created.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN val1 INT, IN val2 INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE TABLE SET value=val1 WHERE cond=val2;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, suppose I want to make the condition optional. I could do this by setting `val2` to `NULL` when calling the procedure and then using an `IF` statement to use the condition if the value is not `NULL`. (In my case, it's safe to assume that `cond=NULL` is not a valid condition to check for.)

This works, but the `UPDATE` query I have is much more complicated and it seems unfortunate to duplicate it just to make the condition optional. I could dynamically construct the query string and pass to `EXECUTE`, but that doesn't feel right either and I lose syntax checking.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I definitely don't want to. The answer given by Mr. Byers solves my problem cleanly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET value = val1
WHERE cond = val2 OR val2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there must be a simple solution. Thanks :)