# MySQL how do you make a conditional where?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Example

I'm trying to create a stored procedure you can call with or without an argument. Is this possible? Moreover, if you supply an argument it will select columns below OR if that name is null if not select just select all

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE showStuff(IN stuff varchar(45))
BEGIN 

SELECT
d.NAME,
s.SIGN,
c.FACE

FROM Format f

JOIN SIGNAL s ON s.SIG_ID=f.SIG_ID
JOIN DEPT d on d.DEP_ID=s.DEP_ID
JOIN CHIM c ON c.F_ID=f.F_ID

WHERE IF(stuff IS NULL, d.NAME=stuff, ??);

ORDER BY d.NAME;

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional WHERE clause in MySQL stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305394/conditional-where-clause-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda like this, although your SQL code is wrong itself.

```
USE [databasename]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedurename] 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
d.NAME,
s.SIGN,
c.FACE

FROM Format f

JOIN SIGNAL s ON s.SIG_ID=f.SIG_ID
JOIN DEPT d on d.DEP_ID=s.DEP_ID
JOIN CHIM c ON c.F_ID=f.F_ID

WHERE IF(stuff IS NULL, d.NAME=stuff, ??)

ORDER BY d.NAME

END
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL:

```
WHERE stuff IS NULL OR d.NAME=stuff;
```

The parameter has to be supplied, but you can pass `NULL`.